# Change file permissions on hfs drive

Tags: mount, macosx, copy, chown, hfs+

I was unable to boot macOS on my mac laptop. I took the drive out to try recover my documents un my ubuntu machine. I installed

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
sudo apt-get install hfsplus
```

So I could access the drive. 
I then mounted the drive with read and write permissions.

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force, rw /dev/sdb2 /media/user/MAC
```

It was somewhat a success as I can view and read some of my Docuemnt folders. However to access others, I would need to change the ownership and access of the folders. I tried with

```
    sudo chown user /media/user/MAC (my user account is 'user')

but im greeted with:

chown: changing ownership of '/media/user/MAC/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/Frameworks/Xalan.framework': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/user/MAC/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/Frameworks/Xerces.framework/Resources': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/user/MAC/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/Frameworks/Xerces.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature/CodeResources': Read-only file system
```

So i think to run fsck but that fails.

```
user@ubuntu: sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb2
** /dev/sdb2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
   Invalid index key
(3, 198)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
   Invalid index key
(3, 198)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
   Invalid index key
(3, 198)
** Repairing volume.
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
   Invalid index key
(3, 198)
```

Anything else I could try? 
I realise I will need to re-install macOS, but I just want to recover some files. Theyre there, I just cant access them due to permission.

Comment: Not permissions - you have the drive mounted read-only. See `chown: changing ownership of '/media/user/MAC/Applications/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6/Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.app/Contents/Frameworks/Xalan.framework': Read-only file system`

Comment: I mounted the drive with  "mount -t hfsplus -o force, rw" the rw being read write.

Comment: that's how you asked for it to be mounted. Look at `mount | grep MAC`.

Comment: How would I mount it as read / write?